# How to backup Windows 10 to a remote server through SSH?

Tags: windows-10, ssh, backup, nas, windows-backup

I have a laptop that I would like to backup to my home NAS even when outside my home network.

How can I configure the native Windows 10 backup tool to send data to my NAS, which is accessible only via SSH?

I am aware of the software Deltacopy but Windows backup has more features and has automatic purging of old backups.

I am aware of VPNs but they seems too difficult to set up for me.

I use NAS4free with rsync server on my NAS.